# Stoping animation on window size with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

Hey I have no experience in javascript, but basically I want to stop this happening when Im on a small device such as an iphone or ipad since im using the twitter bootstrap and once it goes to a mobile device It goes all crazy, is there a way to stop it once the window size goes past 480px?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var offset = $("#lol").offset();
        var topPadding = 55;
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > offset.top) {
                $("#lol").stop().animate({
                    marginTop: $(window).scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
                });
            } else {
                $("#lol").stop().animate({
                    marginTop: 0 
                });
            };
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

By "window size" I assume you mean width:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

   if(this.innerWidth > 480) {
       //your code
   }

});
```

Comment: @user1919077 no problem ^_^